# Setting a String field of an entity using a boolean?

Tags: java, string, boolean, entity, setter

The following is an `Entity` named Person:

```
@Entity
@Table(
    name = "PERSON"
)
public class Person {

    //other fields etc

    @Column(
        name = "PAID_IN_FULL",
        nullable = false
    )
    private String paidInFull;

   public void setPaidInFull(boolean paidInFull) {
        this.paidInFull = paidInFull?"Y":"N";
    }

}
```

Using the setter above, if I were to do the following:

```
person.setPaidInFull(true);
```

What string value would that set it to, would it be `"Y"` or `"N"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paidInFull?"Y":"N";
```

Is another way if saying:

```
if (paidInFull)
    return "Y";
else
    return "N";
```

So if you were to do

```
person.setPaidInFull(true);
```

`this.paidInFull` would be "Y".

Here is a complete example:

```
package nl.testing.startingpoint;

public class Main {
    private static String paidInFull;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        setPaidInFull(true);
        System.out.println(paidInFull);
    }

    public static void setPaidInFull(boolean paidInFull) {
        Main.paidInFull = (paidInFull) ? "Y" : "N";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, so basically setting the value to true will set the value in the database to the string value of "Y"  ?

Comment: Yes, if your database type accepts a String that is (NVARCHAR etc

Answer (score 1):

you could also try the hibernate "yes_no" type.

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Person {

     //other fields etc

     @Column(name = "PAID_IN_FULL", nullable = false)
     @Type(type = "yes_no")
     private Boolean paidInFull;

     public void setPaidInFull(boolean paidInFull) {
          this.paidInFull = paidInFull
     }

}
```

Please refer to https://dzone.com/articles/mapping-boolean-y-or-n-using.